# Android database Connectivity issue

Tags: android

How are you friends.. I am too much tenced because i am trying to connect my simple android apps with database . but it is not working at all. I had found many helpful material from this site. hope u will help me too.

```
    here are the codes for each file. I can also see my db file in data/data directiry. 

    my SQLquery file ....

    package com.example.hotornot;

    //import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.SQLException;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    //import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    //import android.widget.TextView;

    public class SQLquery {
        public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
        public static final String KEY_NAME = "persons_name";
        public static final String KEY_HOTNESS = "persons_hotness";

        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "HotOrNotdb";
        public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "peopleTle";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

        private DbHelper ourHelper;
        private final Context ourContext;
        private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;


         private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
         {

            public DbHelper(Context context) {
                super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null, DATABASE_VERSION);
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }
            private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE proper ("+
                    "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                    "name TEXT NOT NULL,"+
                    "hotness TEXT NOT NULL"+
                    "); ";

            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //          db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_HOTNESS + " TEXT NOT NULL); ");
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

            }


            private static final int old = 1;

            private static final int nwver = 3;

            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int old, int nwvwer) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                db.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS proper");
                //onCreate(db);
            }




         }
         public SQLquery (Context c)
         {

             ourContext = c;

         }
         public SQLquery open() throws SQLException
         {

             ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
             ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
             return this;
         }
         public void close()
         {

             ourHelper.close();

         }
        public long  createEntry(String nam, String hotnes) {

            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();`enter code here`
            cv.put("name",nam);
            cv.put("hotness", hotnes);
            return ourDatabase.insert("proper", null, cv);

        }
    }

    ==========================================================================
    My "hotornot" file...
    package com.example.hotornot;


    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class hotorNot extends Activity implements OnClickListener
    {
       Button sqlUpdate, sqlView;
       EditText sqlName, sqlHotness;
       Boolean didItWork;

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          try{ 
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_hotor_not);
            sqlUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            sqlView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

            sqlName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            sqlHotness = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

            sqlView.setOnClickListener(this);
            sqlUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);
          }catch(Exception exp)
          {

                didItWork = false;
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                d.setTitle("sdfasf");
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText("sdfsdf"+exp.toString());
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();

          }
          }

        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_hotor_not, menu);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId())
            {
            case R.id.button1:
                try{
                String nam = sqlName.getText().toString();
                String Hotnes = sqlHotness.getText().toString();
                SQLquery sqll = new SQLquery(hotorNot.this);
                sqll.open();
                sqll.createEntry(nam,Hotnes);
                sqll.close();
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                d.setTitle("In Button");
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText("Button Pressed");
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
                }catch(SQLiteException e)
                {
                    didItWork = false;
                    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                    d.setTitle("Failed"+e.toString());
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText("Failed"+e.toString());
                    d.setContentView(tv);
                    d.show();
                }finally{

                    if(didItWork){
                        Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                        d.setTitle("Success");
                        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                        tv.setText("Succeeded");
                        d.setContentView(tv);
                        d.show();
                    }

                }

                break;




            }
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


    }

===========================================================
 "AndroidManifest"  file
=============================================================
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hotornot"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".hotorNot"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_hotor_not" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
==========================================================================
First i was getting sqlite exception that my database version is 3 and i have puted wrongly there 1 ... but when i had corrected it . than on clicking to button my apps creashes giving an error of "Unfortunatly hotornot has stopped"
And here are the error logs... 

    07-13 19:43:09.484: E/AndroidRuntime(586): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    07-13 19:43:09.484: E/AndroidRuntime(586): java.lang.NullPointerException
    07-13 19:43:09.484: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at com.example.hotornot.hotorNot.onClick(hotorNot.java:80)
    07-13 19:43:09.484: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
    07-13 19:43:09.484: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
    07-13 19:43:09.484: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    07-13 19:43:09.484: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    07-13 19:43:09.484: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    07-13 19:43:09.484: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    07-13 19:43:09.484: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-13 19:43:09.484: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    07-13 19:43:09.484: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    07-13 19:43:09.484: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    07-13 19:43:09.484: E/AndroidRuntime(586):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    07-13 19:43:10.094: I/dalvikvm(586): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
    07-13 19:43:10.134: I/dalvikvm(586): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'


Please help me...

Thanks ....
```

Comment: Since there are no line numbers in your snippet, what is line 80 of hotornot.java?

Comment: Are you getting a compile error for Boolean didItWork?  That should be a lowercase boolean.  Also what happens when you make the first line of your onCreate -> didItWork = true;?  See if either of those fixes that particular problem.

Comment: Thanks alot ... it worked now by changing boolean. 1 thing more i want to know is that . i am using eclipse juno. on 64-bit, windows 7. and still getting errors. which version is best for 64-bit, windows 7...?

Comment: I wouldn't know how to answer that.  I don't use Eclipse, and I don't use Windows.  What other errors are you getting?

Comment: Than how you are developing android apps ? Which environment you are using ? can you guide me? can u give me your skype?

Comment: Ubuntu, gedit, and Terminal. blog.nraboy.com

Comment: hey . can u please tell me that how can i get user interface for sqlite database for the same file which i have connected with my application

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Can you please give me more information?  Maybe an example?

Comment: can i connect to sql server through android ? mean if i want to connect to sql database, can i do it ?